# Will a thermostatic shower mixer work with two hot supplies?

Tags: shower, valve, plumbing-fixture

I won't go into the specifics here because it'd be far too long, but in a system I'm building I have two hot supplies - one between 25C and 35C, and one between 45C and 70C.

I want an output temperature of 40C, and to mix no additional cold into the system. Will a thermostatic shower mixer do this? The engineer in me says 'yes, the wax will still expand and contract according to the overall temperature', and the plumber in me says 'bUt ThAt'S NoT WhAt It'S DEsiGnEd FoR!!?'

If it won't, has anyone got any smart ideas on how to do this?

Comment: If you feed the cold side with water at 35 deg why do you think it will work properly? Why not just test it... Because Grohe make sure to think « Oh one client will want to feed it with hot on both sides so we will include that in the data sheet »... not.

Comment: ... If it was in the data sheet I wouldn't have needed to ask the question, right? I'd rather not buy an expensive part if it won't do what I need it to, so I asked the question here to see if anyone with more expertise knows what will happen...

As to why I think it might work - it doesn't know the input temperature on either side; the hot side might get fed at 45 or 80 in a domestic system, and cold could be fed at 1 or 25, yet the output remains the same temperature.